# probabilistic location of points with normally distributed distances

Tags: probability, geometry

I have a set of points (position-sensors) in 3D space attached to a structure which may be more or less rigid. At a given time each point may be in observed or unobserved state. My question is how to reconstruct the position of the unobserved sensors from the observed data based on the points' statistical pairwise inter-distances.

Given a set of four points in Euclidean space attached to a completely rigid body, any point's theoretical location may be calculated from the other 3 points locations by trilateration. But how does this extend to the case where there are more than 4 points, and their structural spacing is not rigid, but normally distributed? It may be that the points are different types of sensors with different accuracy, or that the 'rigid body' has some flexibility.